# Ruby exception handling

Tags: ruby

I enclosed some code in a `begin` `rescue` `end` block:

```
begin
  ...
rescue StandardError => e
  puts("Exception #{e} occurred")
  puts("Copying script to error folder.")
  FileUtils.cp("Demo.rb", "C:/Ruby/Failure")
end
```

I'm not sure how to execute a bit of code if no exceptions are thrown so I can copy my script to a success folder. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Would you not just follow your #code with the methods to copy your script, all within the begin ... rescue block?

Comment: That you would.. Not sure why I didn't think of that. Thanks for the help.

Comment: `StandardError` is the default, you can just write `rescue => e`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're thinking about exceptions incorrectly.

The whole point of exceptions is that the main body of your code proceeds as though no exceptions were thrown. *All* of the code inside your `begin` block is *already* executing as though no exceptions were thrown. An exception can interrupt the normal flow of code, and prevent subsequent steps from executing.

You should put your file copy stuff inside the `begin` block:

```
begin
  #code...
  # This will run if the above "code..." throws no exceptions
  FileUtils.cp("Demo.rb", "C:/Ruby/Success")
rescue StandardError => e
  puts("Exception #{e} occurred")
  puts("Copying script to error folder.")
  FileUtils.cp("Demo.rb", "C:/Ruby/Failure")
end
```

Answer (score 4):

You could use `else` to run code only if there wasn't an exception:

```
begin
  # code that might fail
rescue
  # code to run if there was an exception
else
  # code to run if there wasn't an exception
ensure
  # code to run with or without exception
end
```

Comment: `else` seems more appropriate. Otherwise, `rescue` could accidentally rescue an exception that was raised by `FileUtils.cp("Demo.rb", "C:/Ruby/Success")`.